# Convertir imagen a PDF

Tags: laravel

Tengo una funcion que sube una imagen que se envia por un formulario. Todo funciona bien, pero ahora debo de capturar esa imagen y subirla como PDF a mi servidor. Que podria hacer.

Esta es mi funcion:

```
public function uploadImg (){
  $data = $request->all();

   if(isset($data['imagen'])){

            $data['imagen'] = $request->file('imagen')->store('imagenes');

            if(in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($data['imagen'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),["png","jpeg", "jpg"])){

                $image = Image::make(Storage::get($data['imagen']));

                $image->widen(800)
                ->limitColors(255)
                ->encode();

                Storage::put($data['imagen'], (string) $image);


            }   
        }

        $imageSaved = Imagen::create($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que hace falta un poco más de contexto a tu pregunta, pero siguiendo solo el lineamiento de:

1. Ya está subida la imagen en tu servidor.
2. Necesitas cambiar la imagen que tengas a un archivo PDF

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Instalar las siguientes librerías en tu servidor: `libmagickwand-dev imagemagick php-imagick`
- Reinicias los servicios de tu servidor, ya sea Apache o Nginx
- Luego haces lo siguiente

```
$file = storage_path($imageSaved->path); // que sería la ruta donde se guarda tu imagen
    
$image = new Imagick($file);
    
$image->setImageFormat('pdf');
    
$image->writeImage(storage_path('test.pdf')); // sería el nombre con el que quieres guardar tu archivo
```

Y eso sería básicamente todo lo que necesitas hacer. Además, hay librerías como [DomPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) que te pueden ayudar con eso